# Resnet34 first layer 7x7 or 3x3

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, resnet

I've been trying to implement Resnet34 using pytorch but while looking at other's implementations, I see that some of them have 3x3 convlution layers + bn + relu as the first layer. However, on the architecture graph it is written 7x7/2 convolution layer. I am really confused about which one is the right one. By the way, I am training on CIFAR10 and am currently getting 0.9 accuracy after 100 epoches using the 7x7 convolution layers.

Thank you!

[architecture graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kypF.png)

```
self.input_layer = nn.Sequential(             
nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3,bias=False),             
nn.BatchNorm2d(64),             
nn.ReLU(),             
nn.MaxPool2d(3, stride=2,padding=1)         
)
```

Here is the code for my first convolution layer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your datasets. The input size of CIFAR-10 is 32x32. A 3x3 filter may lead to too small feature maps in the following layers and thus hurt the performance of the downstream applications (e.g., style transfer or transfer learning), while ResNet is originally proposed for ImageNet of size 224x224. To this end, some people modify the architecture to better suit their applications.

However, both 7x7 and 3x3 should be fine as long as you specify the architecture clearly (if you are writing a paper or document).

Answer (score 1):

The `7x7` conv at the start of the model was popular for resnet-era CNN models. The thinking was a larger conv at the start would 1) grab larger bits of the full resolution input and 2) increase the receptive field for subsequent layers.

More modern CNNs have moved away from larger convolution kernels in general, preferring to add more layers of `3x3` convs instead of larger kernel layers.